# Distance metric that is robust to collinearity

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, distance, mahalanobis

I'm trying to find a distance metric that takes into account the correlation between vectors. That is, suppose we have matrix $M$ of dimensions $n \times k$, and we take the pairwise distance between all $n$ rows of $M$, yielding a distance matrix $D_0$ of dimensions $n \times n$. Now suppose we append a new column to $M$, which is highly correlated with an existing column, say $cor(M_{*1}, M_{*k+1}) = 0.99$. We then calculate the new pairwise distance between the $n$ rows taking into account this new vector, yielding a new distance matrix $D_1$. What I'm trying to find is a distance metric such that $D_0 \approx D_1$.

Basically the intuition is that adding a bunch of correlated variables shouldn't affect the distance between entries. So suppose we were looking at differences between people's traits, and we measure height, weight, cholesterol, blood pressure, etc. on $n$ people, and then calculate their differences in trait space. If we also measure BMI, which is highly correlated to height and weight, it shouldn't contain much new information, and so the distance measures should be relatively unchanged whether or not we include this.

I've looked at PCA distance, Mahalanobis distances, and a bunch of others. Certainly distances like Chebyshev's maximum metric ($d_{ij} = \max_k |M_{ki} - M_{kj}|$) are by definition robust, but they also loose a ton of information.

Are there any standard solutions to this problem, either via selection of a distance metric or dimensionality reduction procedures that account for this?

EDIT: Here's some code to illustrate how the Mahalanobis goes wrong:

```
set.seed(1)

# generate a random vector
x <- scale(rnorm(100))

# add in 10 correlated columns
X2 <- x
for(i in 1:10){
    X2 <- cbind(X2, sample(c(-1,1), 1)*cbind(x*runif(100, 1-0.05, 1+0.05)))
}   
# scale
X2 <- as.matrix(scale(X2))

# show the covariance matrix
round(cov(X2),4)

         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]   [,10]   [,11]
 [1,]  1.0000  0.9996 -0.9996 -0.9996 -0.9996 -0.9997 -0.9995  0.9996  0.9995 -0.9997 -0.9996
 [2,]  0.9996  1.0000 -0.9994 -0.9991 -0.9991 -0.9994 -0.9990  0.9991  0.9991 -0.9993 -0.9994
 [3,] -0.9996 -0.9994  1.0000  0.9993  0.9993  0.9995  0.9990 -0.9993 -0.9993  0.9992  0.9993
 [4,] -0.9996 -0.9991  0.9993  1.0000  0.9990  0.9994  0.9991 -0.9993 -0.9991  0.9994  0.9992
 [5,] -0.9996 -0.9991  0.9993  0.9990  1.0000  0.9994  0.9993 -0.9994 -0.9993  0.9993  0.9995
 [6,] -0.9997 -0.9994  0.9995  0.9994  0.9994  1.0000  0.9995 -0.9993 -0.9991  0.9995  0.9995
 [7,] -0.9995 -0.9990  0.9990  0.9991  0.9993  0.9995  1.0000 -0.9990 -0.9989  0.9992  0.9994
 [8,]  0.9996  0.9991 -0.9993 -0.9993 -0.9994 -0.9993 -0.9990  1.0000  0.9994 -0.9992 -0.9992
 [9,]  0.9995  0.9991 -0.9993 -0.9991 -0.9993 -0.9991 -0.9989  0.9994  1.0000 -0.9989 -0.9992
[10,] -0.9997 -0.9993  0.9992  0.9994  0.9993  0.9995  0.9992 -0.9992 -0.9989  1.0000  0.9993
[11,] -0.9996 -0.9994  0.9993  0.9992  0.9995  0.9995  0.9994 -0.9992 -0.9992  0.9993  1.0000

# get the inverse of the cov matrix
Sinv <- solve(cov(X2))

# get the pairwise Mahalanobis distance
dst <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(j in i:length(x)){
        dst[i,j] <- dst[j,i] <- sqrt(t(X2[i,] - X2[j,])%*%Sinv%*%t(t((X2[i,] - X2[j,]))))
    }
}

# get the Mahalanobis distance for the first vector only
dst2 <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(j in i:length(x)){
        dst2[i,j] <- dst2[j,i] <- sqrt(t(X2[i,1] - X2[j,1])%*%Sinv[1,1]%*%t(t((X2[i,1] - X2[j,1]))))
    }
}

# plot
plot(dst~dst2)
```

[image]

Ideally what I'm looking for is a metric where these two distance calculates are exactly on the 1-to-1 line. Here, the correlation between the distances is 0.66, despite the vectors being nearly identical (all pairwise correlations > 0.999).

EDIT 2:

As @Noah pointed out below, if we remove any vector (doesn't matter which one) we see a near perfect correlation:

```
# get the pairwise Mahalanobis distance, removing the 10th vector
dst <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(j in i:length(x)){
        dst[i,j] <- dst[j,i] <- sqrt(t(X2[i,-10] - X2[j,-10])%*%Sinv[-10,-10]%*%t(t((X2[i,-10] - X2[j,-10]))))
    }
}

# get the Mahalanobis distance for the first vector only
dst2 <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(j in i:length(x)){
        dst2[i,j] <- dst2[j,i] <-  sqrt(t(X2[i,1] - X2[j,1])%*%Sinv[1,1]%*%t(t((X2[i,1] - X2[j,1])))))
    }
}

# plot
plot(dst~dst2)
```

[image]

Any intuition as to why this is the case? The solution can't be to always remove a vector at random (as the vector might have low correlation with others). Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: What is wrong with the Mahalanobis distance, which does exactly this?

Comment: @Noah - that was my thought too, but from exploring it, it actually does the exact opposite. Because it can be seen as rescaling of a Euclidean distance, it actually stretches the correlated axes, and accentuates the differences. See the code above.

Comment: Well, from the linear correlation p.o.w. BMI is a pretty new information to height and weight because BMI is not a linear function of them. It is normal to include both BMI and height along each other in the analysis.

Comment: If you see that a feature is almost a (linear) duplicate of another one, for it correlates 0.99 with it, why include the duplicate at all? Or you might take the mean between the two features and use that.

Comment: I don't know if it would fit your pupose, but you could try using Mahalanobis distance based on a robust scale estimate rather than the usual sample covariance matrix. One option could be the Minimum Covariance Determinant method (Rousseeuw and Van Driessen 1999) or the Minimum Volume Ellipsoide one (Van Aelst and Rousseeuw 2009), which you can compute in R using the cov.rob() function of the MASS package with method = "mcd" or method = "mve".

Comment: In the example in which you state that "Mahalanobis goes wrong", what is the correlation between dst and dst2? You add 10 variables that are correlated but different to your original data, so you shouldn't expect the relation to be perfect. I'm not sure it "goes so wrong" here.

Comment: @ttnphns - the extreme correlation is just for illustrative purposes. What I want is a metric that incorporates collinearity in a continuous fashion. So, as correlation goes from zero to 1, it accounts for this in the metric (e.g., by using some aspect of the covariance metric).

Comment: By the way, Mahalanobis is invariant against scaling, so all that scaling in the example looks superfluous. I have no idea why you scale the x even twice in the beginning.

Comment: @ChristianHennig - I just added some more detail about the correlation. In the example, all the pairwise correlations are >0.999, i.e., they are nearly the identical vector, and yet the Mahalanobis correlations are 0.67. Obviously Mahalanobis is doing what it's supposed to do, but from a dimension reduction perspective, this is a bad result. It shows the Mahalanobis distance is incredibly fragile to the addition of collinear variables.

Comment: @Pohoua - thanks for the suggestion. I the cov.rob() function, but it actually makes things worse. The issue doesn't seem to be the estimation of the cov matrix. It's just the actual metric itself isn't taking into account collinearity (at least in the way I want).

Comment: Simply compute the weighted Euclidean distance with the weight pertaining to each term (i.e. each variable) equal to 1-R^2, where R^2 is the squared multiple correlation of the variable with the rest of the variables.

Comment: Or you might prefer you define the "R^2" as the mean squared correlation with the rest of the variables. This will correspond to a different concept of what "collinearity" is.

Comment: @ttnphns - I like this idea. is there a standard metric that this corresponds to? I'm up for doing ad hoc stuff, but ideally would like to be good to know the properties of the metric.

Comment: @ttnphns - a slight tweak seems necessary. You have to use the sequential R2 to ensure that at least one correlated vector gets full weight. So you set $R^2_1 = 1$, and then for $R^2_2$ you regress $X_{.2}$ against  $X_{.1}$, and for $R^2_3$ you regress $X_{.3}$ against  $X_{.1}  + X_{.2}$, and so on. This way you're always weighting each subsequent vector by its residual power. Seems to work well, but still wondering if it's based on a previously documented metric.

Comment: A few observations: 1) the formula for `dst2` is wrong; you forgot a `sqrt()`, 2) if you include all but one variable in a new distance, that distance is correlated with `dst2` .9996. It's the 11th variable that ruins it (it doesn't matter which variable is removed).

Comment: @Noah - thanks for nothing the typo. You're right, if we use n-1 variables it's almost perfectly correlated. Any intuition as to why this would be? Is it just that the cov matrix isn't full rank, or similar? I can't imagine the solution is to always remove one vector.

Comment: The typo remains, but yeah, I can't figure out why this is occurring either.

Comment: @Noah -- it seems to be somewhat unique to this setting. If instead you have two independent vectors and add in vectors which are each correlated highly with one of them, you no longer can just remove one to get the perfect fit. So there must be some way to figure out what/how many to remove.

Comment: The dst2 formulae both look messy. Why do you assign dst2[j,i] inside a square root? They're also different from each other, but both not looking good.

Comment: I also don't get why you cycle through all possible values of i and j, still assign both dst2[i,j] and dst2[j,i] each time, same for dst. As long as the code is not clean, I'd not be too surprised by strange results.

Comment: Try using Hotelling T2 Distance metric. This works on the Components variance and calculates the distance between PROJECTION and the PCA HYPERPLANE.
Ref: https://learnche.org/pid/latent-variable-modelling/principal-component-analysis/hotellings-t2-statistic

Comment: user3037237, good note. The weight for the variable, based on its R^2, should assume variables are added in some determined _sequence_. Weights for all the "old" variables remain still when a new variable is added and its weight is estimated. Otherwise we may end up with all or many weights suddenly turning to 0 because of the emergent multicollinearity.

Comment: The properties of a weighted eucludean distance are as of the unweighted one. Weights simply redistribute contributions of the terms (variables, dimensions) into the distance value.

Comment: @ChristianHennig -- Cool. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AtulMishra -- this in interesting, thanks. But can you calculate pairwise distances, or only relative to the centroid of the distribution? It also likely suffers from the PCA distance approaches, in that the addition of collinear variables means the first PC overweights the importance of this axis. I sort of want the opposite -- to remove the undue influence of the collinear variables. But I'll check this out and see how it looks.